# Is there any way to return HTML in a PHP function? using a string

Tags: php, html

i need to return information from a php grab function in html 
so i can post it in my form.

Comment: HTML is just text. You can put it into a string and `echo` it.

Comment: what is a 'php grab function'? You need to use well known terms if you expect anyone to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do something like this on a page called demo.php...

```
<?php 
function grabHTML(){
   //could just display some html or query database for stuff..
   echo "<p>some html</p>"; 
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<?php grabHTML(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?php echo 'test'; ?>"/>
```

?

Comment: this not what i am asking for .. but thank you 
i have a function that return information from a database
and i need to build a function that display this information

Comment: @mohamem23 see my answer below i believe this is what you will want.